# Not authorized to control networking in SSH console

Tags: ssh, networkmanager

I want to control Network manager from the command-line. This worked well enough in Ubuntu 10.04 (with cnetworkmanager, nmcli is another possible choice).

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 however, a D-Bus exception is raised when I attempt to activate a connection from within a **SSH terminal**:

> org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.PermissionDenied:
>   Not authorized to control networking.

It may have to do with /etc/dbus-1/system.d/NetworkManager.conf; where else to look for a clue ?

Comment: If you aren't ssh'd in do you get the same issue?  What user account are you running the command as?

Comment: In a gnome session I don't get the same issue -- with the same (admin) user account.

Answer (score 0):

Why   you dont use  cd /etc/network/

In there  you can manage networks   and  in /etc/resolv.conf

You need root permition

Comment: Because I want to activate connections from a *normal user's point of view*: user is connected to the internet on machine A, which is linked to machine B with an ethernet cable. Sometimes A shares its internet connection via Ethernet, then the user who logged into B using ssh wants to activate a different connection than the link-local one -- maybe it's not the right place to ask